# Firebase OnMessage function refreshes widget

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

I am using firebase cloud messaging to push notification on my app that contains a chat page.

I defined my firebase push functions on my main.dart as below:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
   onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
     print("onMessage: $message");
     //_showItemDialog(message);
   },
   onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
   onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
     print("onLaunch: $message");
     //_navigateToItemDetail(message);
   },
   onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
     print("onResume: $message");
     //_navigateToItemDetail(message);
   },
 );
```

When chat widget opened and i receive a push notification, my OnMessage method is reached normally.

The question is: what is the best way to refresh my chat page considering that the opened page is not the same one where the reached OnMessage function is declared?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used following peice of code for different question on StackOverflow. But the problem there is entirely different from yours, so pasting relevant code.

You can use BLOC here. FCM/`NotificationService` will send notifications to BLOC/`NotificationsBloc` and all the widgets that need notifications can subscribe for the notifications. Sample implementation

#### BLOC

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class LocalNotification {
  final String type;
  final Map data;

  LocalNotification(this.type, this.data);
}

class NotificationsBloc {
  NotificationsBloc._internal();

  static final NotificationsBloc instance = NotificationsBloc._internal();

  final BehaviorSubject<LocalNotification> _notificationsStreamController = BehaviorSubject<LocalNotification>();

  Stream<LocalNotification> get notificationsStream {
    return _notificationsStreamController;
  }

  void newNotification(LocalNotification notification) {
    _notificationsStreamController.sink.add(notification);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _notificationsStreamController?.close();
  }
}
```

#### FCM Listener (NotificationService)

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

import 'notifications_bloc.dart';

class LocalNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  bool _started = false;

  LocalNotificationService._internal();

  static final LocalNotificationService instance = LocalNotificationService._internal();

  // ********************************************************* //
  // YOU HAVE TO CALL THIS FROM SOMEWHERE (May be main widget)
  // ********************************************************* //
  void start() {
    if (!_started) {
      _start();
      _started = true;
      _refreshToken();
    }
  }

  void _refreshToken() {
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then(_tokenRefresh, onError: _tokenRefreshFailure);
  }

  void _start() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
    _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen(_tokenRefresh, onError: _tokenRefreshFailure);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: _onMessage,
      onLaunch: _onLaunch,
      onResume: _onResume,
    );
  }

  void _tokenRefresh(String newToken) async {
    print(" New FCM Token $newToken");
  }

  void _tokenRefreshFailure(error) {
    print("FCM token refresh failed with error $error");
  }

  Future<void> _onMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage $message");
    if (message['notification'] != null) {
      final notification = LocalNotification("notification", message['notification'] as Map);
      NotificationsBloc.instance.newNotification(notification);
      return null;
    }
    if (message['data'] != null) {
      final notification = LocalNotification("data", message['data'] as Map);
      NotificationsBloc.instance.newNotification(notification);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("onLaunch $message");
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _onResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print("onResume $message");
    return null;
  }
}
```

#### Finally in your Widget

```
  Stream<LocalNotification> _notificationsStream;

  @override 
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _notificationsStream = NotificationsBloc.instance.notificationsStream;
    _notificationsStream.listen((notification) {
      // TODO: Implement your logic here
      print('Notification: $notification');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @chenna - Very nicely structured - Just a doubt - In the widget "listen" function will keep listening to notifications - based on the notification I have to redirect users to different pages which as per my limited knowledge goes in _onLaunch & _onResume - So, how to connect listen body to _onLaunch?

Comment: `onLaunch` and `onResume` are FCM specific, nothing to do with widgets. If you want to navigate to different page based on notification, why not do something like `Navigator.push(...)` or equivalent in `listen` call back?

Comment: I have an error on _notificationsStream?.dispose();
The method dispose isn't defined for class Stream.

Comment: @rstrelba You can omit that line. Its only for cleanup, if it doesn't have that method, there is nothing to cleanup. I would remove that line.

Comment: I did it, but right now I recieve multiple events )). One per listen method.

Comment: I figured out this issue. I declare StreamSubscription<LocalNotification> _subscription; 
_subscription = _notificationsStream.listen((notification) ...
and finally in dispose()
_subscription.cancel();

Thanks.

Comment: You are an awesome man. Everything well structured.